# How do I make a brush with overlapping shapes aligned to the path in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, brush

I am using Illustrator to apply a custom pattern brush on the path of a circle to create and image like so:

[image]

But I can't get my shape to repeat across the circle line properly and overlap itself, I end up with something like this:

[image]

I can get the overlap to work if I use a `Scatter Brush` but then I don't get the rotation like the `Pattern Brush`:

[image]

What is the best way to achieve my result?

Comment: find the `Rotation relative to` field in the `Scatter Brush Option` dialog, and change it to `Path` instead of 'Page'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a second problem with pattern brushes here - even if you got around the overlapping problem, the straight lines would become distorted (curved).

**Try `Effects > Distort & Transform > Transform`.** Copies, moves, rotates, with overlaps, without distortion:

[image]

For a circle, make sure `Copies` `x` `Angle` `=` `360`

Answer (score 2):

Pattern brushes are dependent upon their tile. If the tile artwork does not overlap itself, then the brush isn't going to either. You can't force pattern brush tiles to overlap themselves within the brush.

A blend would probably be a better solution for what you are after:

[image]

Or an effect....

[image]

Comment: Is there a way of doing this _plus_ rotating around the circle? like my example image?

Comment: see updated answer